# WebStorm/PhpStorm: navigating by file stopped working

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

The `Ctrl+Shift+N` opens the dialog box but.. does not find any file any more

[image]

I restarted the IDE: same problem: any idea on how to fix that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just found the solution: Invalidate Cache and restart the IDE fixed the bug !

From the menu:

`File > Invalidate Caches/Restart`

Comment: Cheers, fixed it for me.

Comment: Cheers indeed. You're a lifesaver :-)